# try catch confusion on my program

Tags: java, list, try-catch

I am developing a small snake and ladder game in which I am generating the snakesgenerator class which verifies whether the snakes are logically construct the snakes or not.

I have taken the head and tail arrays for head and tails of snakes.

The snake class has the `getTail()`, `getHead()` methods which return the object position on the board.

`position.getPositionNumber()` returns the integer value range from 1 to 100.

I have arrraylist of snakes in the class board.

The snakegenerator is a class which verifies the snakes are logically correct or not (it has to remove the snakes which are wrong in construction).

If the two snakes have the same head then it has to neglect one snake (latest snake) and give the board with other snakes.

This is the board class:

```
public class Board {

    private int[] head = { 15,16,15,15};
    private int[] tail = {3,4,5,6};
    List<Snake> snakes = new ArrayList();
 public void getBoard()  {
        Snake snake;

 ListIterator<Snake> listIterator = snakes.listIterator();
        while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
            snake = listIterator.next();
            System.out.println(snake.getHead().getPositionNumber());
        }

             SnakesGenerator snakesGenerator = new SnakesGenerator(snakes);

          snakes=snakesGenerator.addSnakes();
          listIterator = snakes.listIterator();
            while (listIterator.hasNext()) {
                snake = listIterator.next();
                System.out.println(snake.getHead().getPositionNumber());
            }
    }         
}
```

snakegenerator class is given below..

```
public class SnakesGenerator {

    List<Snake> snakes = new ArrayList();

    public SnakesGenerator(List<Snake> snakes) {
        super();
        this.snakes = snakes;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Snake> addSnakes() {
        Snake snake;
        Snake snakePrevious = null;

        Collections.sort(snakes, new SnakesCompator());
            int i=0;
        // ListIterator<Snake> listIterator = snakes.listIterator();
        // System.out.println("hai this is addsnakes");
        for (Snake s : snakes)
            System.out.println(s.getTail().getPositionNumber());

                snakePrevious =snakes.get(0);

        System.out.println("before the method execution"
                + snakePrevious.getTail().getPositionNumber());
        for(i=1;i<3;i++) {

            snake=snakes.get(i);
            System.out.println(snake.getTail().getPositionNumber());

            try {
                if (snakePrevious.getHead().getPositionNumber() == snake
                        .getHead().getPositionNumber()) {
                    snakes.remove(snake);
                    throw new Exception("two snakes have same head..");

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                for (Snake s : snakes)
                              System.out.println(s.getTail().getPositionNumber());
            }
            snakePrevious = snake;
        }
        return snakes;
    }
}
```

I am able to remove only one duplicate and the program is terminating.

I think I have the problem with using the try catch block.

Comment: By 161 rep. you should have figured out how to format code and use your shift key at the start of sentences.  I am not going to try to wade through that mess.

Comment: I think the last try-catch block doesn't make much sense. Why throw a exception within the if?

Comment: You should not use try catch for flow control. Exceptions should be used to signal exceptional behaviour, in your case you throw an exception for expected behaviour. See here for more info: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are throwing an exception but because you are ignoring it i.e. not printing it out, you have no idea what it is or what is causing it.

I suspect your problem is that when you remove a snake you have less items than you expected and your you are trying to get an element from the `snakes` which is no longer there.

I suggest you try debugging your program with your debugger by stepping through the code and getting an understanding as to what it is really doing.

BTW: Throwing an exception and catching it immediately is confusing and pointless.

Comment: i am throwing the exception to tell the developer of the game that so and so snake is not added...

Comment: As you catch the exception immediately, the message that you have put into the exception will never be written. I think you have some misunderstandings about the usage of exceptions.

Comment: @PratapMurukutla That not what the exception says, and you discard the exception anyway so it wouldn't matter if it did. It not clear to my why the code in the catch block is not where the Exception is thrown.